Will a 10-speed Tiagra shifter work with 9-speed sora drivetrain
I'm thinking of getting a 10-speed Tiagra shifter. Will it work with a 9-speed sora drivetrain (front derailleur, 9spd rear derailleur, 9spd chain and cassette, and 9spd crankset)

You can do this if it is the older Tiagra 4600 but you will also need the 10sp cassette and chain.
If you want the newer Tiagra 4700 shifters, you will need the 10sp cassette and chain and also the front and rear derailleurs.
Consider trying to buy a groupset bundle, there are often good deals.

No, it will not work, the cable pull ratios are different.  Not 100% certain about the front compatibility in older versions, but the 4700 is definitely incompatible.
I do not see a reason to not just buy Sora shifters, they work well. The only reason could be a change to hydraulic disc brakes.

@Rеnаud I meant hydraulic brakes, obviously... My own Claris bike had mechanical disc brake already some 6 years ago.

Your answer is wrong: the gap between 9s sprockets and 10sp sprockets is different. You mean Tiagra 4600 will work with the Sora derailleur but only with a 10sp cassette.

@Noise Yes, I did. In fact I only added it later because I realized that someone will come and point out that there is in fact some compatibility in older versions, but I mixed it up in the end. I will just remove the to-be forgotten version completely.
